# How to implement Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) to connect to LinkedIn API from Microsoft Flow

Tags: linkedin-api, power-automate

I would like to connect to the LinkedIn API by the use of the HTTP action in Microsoft Flow. To be able to connect to the LinkedIn API I have to set up a Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth). What URL should I use as Authorized Redirect URLs? Is that the same URL as for a custom Flow connector? I've tried that URL (https://europe-001.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any guidance?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow

Answer (score 0):

Go to Linkedin - Myapp - Create app
Other information you can take from your link